# java convert flat array structure to hirerarchical

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, object, data-structures

I have java array of below value object in format like

```
[
{grandParent1,parent1,child1},
{grandParent1,parent1,child2},
{grandParent1,parent2,child3},
{grandParent2,parent1,child4},
{grandParent2,parent2,child5},
{grandParent2,parent3,child6},
]
```

and need to convert to hierarchical structure like below

```
{
  grandParent1
  {
     parent1
     {
         child1{
         },
         child2{
         }
     },
       parent2
     {
         child3{
         } 
     }
   },

   grandParent2
  {
     parent1
     {
         child4{
         } 
     },
      parent2
     {
         child5{
         } 
     },
     parent3
     {
         child6{
         } 
     }
   }
}
```

We have flat structure value of object class having properties like below.

```
 public class TestVO {
    private String grandParent;

    private String parent;

    private String child;

    public String getGrandParent() {
        return grandParent;
    }

    public void setGrandParent(String grandParent) {
        this.grandParent = grandParent;
    }

    public String getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(String parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(String child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

}
```

Kindly suggest some logic which will be efficient and with better performance to convert flat to hierarchical structure in java objects.

**UPDATE**
 I have some more fields at each grandparent,parent and child level. Can we use it in logic . Please find the below short form of updated object. here grandParentId,parentId AND childId will be unique at each level.

```
public class TestVO {
private String grandParentId;
private String grandParentFirstName;
private String grandParentLastName;
private String parentId;
private String parentFirstName;
private String parentLastName;
private String childId;
private String childFirstName;
private String childLastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 `Stream`s with `groupingBy` collector:

```
List<TestVO> list = ...
Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>>
    map = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestVO::getGrandParent,
                                             Collectors.groupingBy(TestVO::getParent,
                                                                   Collectors.mapping(TestVO::getChild, 
                                                                                      Collectors.toList()))));
```

This will create a `Map` whose keys are the grand parents and whose values are inner `Map`s where the keys are the parents and the values are the corresponding children.

As for your updated question, I suggest you create a class for each level of the hierarchy - `GrandParent`, `Parent` and `Child`. Each class will contain the corresponding 3 properties. Now, if you change `TestVO` to contain a `GrandParent` instance, a `Parent` instance and a `Child` instance instead of the 9 properties, you can use the same code as above to generate a `Map<GrandParent,Map<Parent,List<Child>>>`. You'll have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in both `GrandParent` and `Parent` classes.

If you can't change your input object as suggested, you can add a `map()` step to the above `Stream` pipeline (before the `collect()` step) that converts a `TestVO` instance to some new class instance that contains a `GrandParent`, `Parent` and `Child`.

Comment: Thank you for your help but actual situation is quiet different means I have some more fields at each grandparent,parent and child level. Can we use it in logic . Please find the below short form of updated object.
here Id will be unique. 

 public class TestVO {
    private String grandParentId;
    private String grandParentFirstName;
    private String grandParentLastName;

    private String parentId;
    private String parentFirstName;
    private String parentLastName;

    private String childId;
    private String childFirstName;
    private String childLastName;
}

Comment: Eran, Thank you for your help . I cant change input so trying 2nd way.
I created new class in hierarchical manner TestHierarchy>TestGrandParent->TestParent->TestChild
And i added map like below.     .map(TestHierarchy). its showing error

 map = list.stream()
       .map(TestHierarchy)
               .collect(....

Could you please help how to add map

Comment: is there way rather than String use it for objects

Comment: @sardarCoder create a class (let's call it `TestClasses`) that contains a GrandParent instance, a Parent instance and a Child instance, define a constructor for that class that accepts a `TestVO` object, and add a `map(TestClasses::new)` step before `collect`.

Comment: I added as you suggested but it gives me below error
The method collect(Collector<? super TestHierarchy,A,R>) in the type Stream<TestHierarchy> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<TestVO,capture#7-of ?,Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>>>)

I created TestHierarchy class with below properties
 private TestGrandParent testGrandParent;
  private TestParent testParent;
  private TestChild testChild;

Comment: @sardarCoder you also have to change the method references passed to the Collectors methods. For example, change `TestVO::getGrandParent` to `TestHierarchy::getGrandParent`. And you have to change the type of the output Map (change all the Strings to the classes that replace them).